# Is there a Ruby on Rails based torrent tracker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bittorrent

I'm looking for a torrent tracker written in Ruby on Rails ([TBDev.net](http://www.tbdev.net/home/index.php) style or so). Is there a ready made package?

Another option: Is there a robust torrent tracker software that can act as a backend for which I can write a RoR front end?

Answer (score 5):

BitTorrent tracker backend is a relatively compact piece, take a look at https://github.com/shurikk/bttrack that is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Something like the [Hydra Project](http://code.google.com/p/hydraproject/)? It seems to be abandoned though.